# FromForm not deserializing FormData object to use in the route's parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an update route in my asp.net core backend server

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromForm] GearItemViewModel gearItem)
{
    ...
}
```

From my angular app I am sending a request that contains FormData. The FormData has two objects, one is called "gearImages" another one is called "gearItem".

```
this.selectedFileFormData.append(
  "gearItem",
  JSON.stringify({ id: 1, name: "tst", price: 30, inStock: false })
);



for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
  this.selectedFileFormData.append("gearImages", filesObj[index]);
}
```

When I make the following request:

```
return this.http
  .patch<GearItem>(
    `${this.merchandiseUrl}/${gearItem.id}`,
    gearItem.formData
  )
```

The request arrives at the correct route, but the argument for the `gearItem` is not populated with valid data. It has all `null` values.

When I modify the route to accept:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromForm] List<IFormFile> gearImages)
{
    ...
}
```

The argument gets successfully populated.

I can deserialize the gearItem object just fine manually from the request object:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GearItemViewModel>(Request.Form["gearItem"]);
```

Any ideas why this may not be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The reason why it doesn't work

Your first action method is

> *public async Task Update([FromForm] GearItemViewModel gearItem)*

Typically, it will accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` **or `multipart/form-data`**. However, when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you **cannot send the image file at the same time** (unless you encode the image file , eg `base64`, but that' not good). Because of the same reason, you **can't send the payload in `application/json`**.

That means your action method expects data in **`multipart/form-data`** as below:

```
POST /.../Update HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----My.Boundary

------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

1    
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

tst    
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price"

30
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="inStock"

false
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gearImages"; filename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{bytes-of-your-image1}
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gearImages"; filename="2.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{bytes-of-your-image2}
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gearImages"; filename="3.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{bytes-of-your-image3}
------My.Boundary--
```

However, what you send to server is :

```
POST /.../Update HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----My.Boundary

------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gearItem"

{ "id": 1, "name": "tst", "price": 30, "inStock": false }
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gearImages"; filename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{bytes-of-your-image1}
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gearImages"; filename="2.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{bytes-of-your-image2}
------My.Boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gearImages"; filename="3.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{bytes-of-your-image3}
------My.Boundary--
```

As a result, you get no `gearItem` on server side.

---

#### How to solve

Suppose your `GearItemViewModel` is :

```
public class GearItemViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool InStock { get; set; }

    public IList<IFormFile> GearImages {get;set;}
}
```

You need construct the FormData as below (I just copy & paste your code with a little change)

```
this.selectedFileFormData.append("id","1");
this.selectedFileFormData.append("name","tst");
this.selectedFileFormData.append("price","30");
this.selectedFileFormData.append("inStock","false");
for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
  this.selectedFileFormData.append("gearImages", this.filesObj[index]);
}
```

Or you could initialize the `FormData` with a form element:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("yourFormId");
var selectedFileFormData= new FormData(formElement);
```

And then send the `FormData`, you'll get the payload automatically:

```
this.http.patch<GearItem>(`${this.merchandiseUrl}/${gearItem.id}`, this.selectedFileFormData)
  .subscribe(res => {
      ...
  })
```

---

**[Edit]**

> *Do you know if its possible to use formData and append for example an object that represents "Sizes"*

Suppose the shape of `Size` & `GearSize` is :

```
// typescript 
enum Size { NONE = 0, XS = 1, S = 2, XXL = 6 }

interface GearSize 
{
  id : Number,
  available: boolean,
  color : string,
  size: Size,
}
```

let's say you have 4 gearSizes :

```
var gearSizes: GearSize[] = [
  {id:1,available:true, color:"red",size:Size.S},
  {id:2,available:false, color:"blue",size:Size.XS},
  {id:3,available:true, color:"green",size:Size.XXL},
  {id:4,available:true, color:"yellow",size:Size.NONE},
];
```

To send these gearSizes, just create fields that has the form of `sizes[index].property`:

```
// a helper function that appends its fields to formdata
appendOneGearSize(formData: FormData, index: Number, size:GearSize){
    formData.append(`sizes[${index}].id`,size.id.toString());
    formData.append(`sizes[${index}].available`,size.avaiable.toString());
    formData.append(`sizes[${index}].color`,size.color.toString());
    formData.append(`sizes[${index}].size`,size.size.valueOf().toString());
}

for(let index=0; index < gearSizes.length; index++){
  this.appendOneGearSize(this.selectedFileFormData,index,gearSizes[index]);
}
```

Finally, here's the server side action method :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromForm] GearItemViewModel gearItem)
{
    ...
}
```

**A working demo :** 
[image]

Comment: I will try this tonight. So even though I am sending the gearItem object in the formData from the front end, NOT under a single key name called "gearItem" => {...obj...}, BUT instead I am sending it as individual key value paris on the formData object, in my asp.net core action I can expect the following to work? `[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromForm] List<IFormFile> gearImages, [FromForm] GearItemViewModel gearItem)
{
    ...
}`. Where gearItem would get automatically deserialized and the argument would be populated?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh *in my asp.net core action I can expect the following to work?*: Yes, it should work as expected.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh *Where gearItem would get automatically deserialized and the argument would be populated?*: The `[FromForm]` attribute instructs the model binder to bind parameter from form (which resides in `Request.Body`). Because you're sending the payload in`multipart/form-data`, the ASP.NET Core is able to find all the related fields and create the `gearItem` instance for you automatically.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to use `formData` and append for example an object that represents "Sizes". This `JSON` would have things like `available: boolean`, `color: string`, but on the server have the `GearItem` model have a List<GearItemSize> object, then using `[FromForm]` and automatically populate not only the `GearItem` properties but also the list of `GearItemSize` which would have matching properties on back-end server for `available: bool`, and `color: string`. I cant seem to get this list to be populated. I can get it to work I my list is `List<string>` but List<GearItemSize> nogo

Comment: @O.MeeKoh I believe there're two ways to do that. But before I write code and test it, could you please tell me the definition of `GearItem` class & `GearItemSize` ? Sounds like `GearItem` has a property of `List<GearItemSize> sizes` ?

Comment: `class GearItem { public long? Id {get; set;} public string Name {...} public decimal Price {...} public bool InStock {...} public IEnumerable<GearSize> Sizes {...}}` then GearSize looks like `class GearSize{ public long? Id {...} public bool Available {...} public string Color {...} public Size Size {...}}` and size is an enum `enum Size { NONE = 0, XS = 1, S = 2 ... XXL = 6}`.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh It's too long to post my reply as a comment, so I update my answer. Please check :)

Comment: Ha! Wow very impressive. You are a true coding gangster. Much respect, and I appreciate the time you put into trying to help me out. I wish there was more I could do.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh Glad to hear it helps :)

Comment: Would you care to explain this part a little bit? `formData.append(`sizes[${index}].id`` how or why it works?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh  the trick is the server side action method expects a form `GearItemViewModel gearItem`, the `GearItemViewModel` has a property of `IEnumerable<GearSize> Sizes { get; set; }`. So it expects a `sizes[]` array in the form. That's why I use the` sizes[index]`. And because the `GearSize` has a property `id` , so I change the field name to `sizes[index].id` (the same goes for other fields) so that the `ModelBinder` is able to bind these fields automatically. By the way, I made a mistake (typo) in my code , I've renamed `avaiable` to `available`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with asp.net core FromForm accepts application/x-www-form-urlencoded content.....  If you want to use json you could use FromBody instead.